# Change the color accordingly

Tags: r, shiny

Please execute the following code and select the darkly in the theme selector, then the numbers in table are vanished, since the color of number is white in the darkly, but the background is also white.

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

editTable <- function(DF, outdir=getwd(), outfilename="table"){
    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(



        shiny::tags$head(
            shinythemes::themeSelector(),

            shiny::tags$style(shiny::HTML("




.ui-draggable {
 z-index: 3;
 background-color: #CCCCFF;

    "))

        ),#taghead




        titlePanel("Edit and save a table"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                helpText("Shiny app based on an example given in the rhandsontable package.", 
                         "Right-click on the table to delete/insert rows.", 
                         "Double-click on a cell to edit"),

                wellPanel(
                    h3("Table options"),
                    radioButtons("useType", "Use Data Types", c("TRUE", "FALSE"))
                ),
                br(), 

                wellPanel(
                    h3("Save"), 
                    actionButton("save", "Save table")
                )        

            ),

            mainPanel(
                shiny::absolutePanel(        draggable = T, style ="red",fixed=TRUE,
                  h3("Table options"),

                rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
                h3("Table options")

                )
            )
        )
    ))

    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        values <- reactiveValues()

        ## Handsontable
        observe({
            if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
                DF = hot_to_r(input$hot)
            } else {
                if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
                    DF <- DF
                else
                    DF <- values[["DF"]]
            }
            values[["DF"]] <- DF
        })

        output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
            DF <- values[["DF"]]
            if (!is.null(DF))
                rhandsontable(DF, useTypes = as.logical(input$useType), stretchH = "all")
        })

        ## Save 
        observeEvent(input$save, {
            finalDF <- isolate(values[["DF"]])
            saveRDS(finalDF, file=file.path(outdir, sprintf("%s.rds", outfilename)))
        })

    })

    ## run app 
    runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
    return(invisible())
}



editTable(DF=data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4)))
```

The following image shows the  vanishing of number in cells when the theme is darkly.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Is there any method to avoid such vanishing?
I am not sure how to avoid by css.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has to to with the way the package authors of `Rhandsontable` have defined their CSS for the tables. They have explicitly set the color of

1. the table cells background color to be white
2. The header text color to be black

But they have not set the color of the text in the cells explicitly. So what's happening is that shinythemes is changing the text color to white but the explicitly set background color is not being overridden by shinythemes.

I would suggest switching to using `dataTableOutput()` and `renderDataTable()`.

```
library(shiny)

DF=data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shiny::tags$head(
    shinythemes::themeSelector(),

    shiny::tags$style(shiny::HTML("

                                  .ui-draggable {
                                  z-index: 3;
                                  }


                                  "))

    ),#taghead




  titlePanel("Edit and save a table"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Shiny app based on an example given in the rhandsontable package.", 
               "Right-click on the table to delete/insert rows.", 
               "Double-click on a cell to edit"),

      wellPanel(
        h3("Table options"),
        radioButtons("useType", "Use Data Types", c("TRUE", "FALSE"))
      ),
      br(), 

      wellPanel(
        h3("Save"), 
        actionButton("save", "Save table")
      )        

    ),

    mainPanel(
      shiny::absolutePanel(        draggable = T, style ="red",fixed=TRUE,
                                   h3("Table options"),

                                   dataTableOutput("hot"),
                                   h3("Table options")

      )
    )
  )
    ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  ## Handsontable
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
      DF = hot_to_r(input$hot)
    } else {
      if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
        DF <- DF
      else
        DF <- values[["DF"]]
    }
    values[["DF"]] <- DF
  })

  output$hot <- renderDataTable({
    DF <- values[["DF"]]
    if (!is.null(DF))
      DF
  })

  ## Save 
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    finalDF <- isolate(values[["DF"]])
    saveRDS(finalDF, file=file.path(outdir, sprintf("%s.rds", outfilename)))
  })

})

  ## run app 
runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Also a side note, we should not put the shiny app itself in a function. This will not work when deploying to shinyapps.io or Rsconnect. The app itself needs to be in a single app.R file or seperate ui.R and server.R files.

Comment: Thank you,.... but the `renderDataTable()` cannot edit its numbers by hands. On the other hand, `Rhandsontable` can edit by hands, Thank you for your side note, when I publish shiny  code, I will write separately. I will try to specify the css for numbers in cells, but, it also changes all css of GUI.  I wonder there is a way to change color oc character only in a panel.

Comment: There is a way to change the color of the text in the table only, use a more selective CSS selector specifying the ID of the table.